# Echoing data with single and double quotes in php

Tags: php

what could be best way to print data below since am having single quotes intercalated with double quotes

```
echo '
<div class=" w3-display-container">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'"
  class="w3-button w3-gray w3-large w3-display-topright">&times;</span>


<div id='alerts_create_room' class='w3-panel w3-red'>No Data Found for the Search Group.</div></div>';
```

Comment: The best way would be to not make that a PHP block at all. http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: you can also create a php variable and concate it with string. it solves your problem.

Comment: If all you need to do is echo it out on the spot, I'd go with what CBroe said and linked with. Just end the PHP and start standard html, then pick up PHP again. -- However if you need to wrap it into a variable, to be echo'd out much later... (or saved to file, or cached, whatever) then doing one of the answers below of "escaping" the single or double quotes to conform, is really the best you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '
<div class=" w3-display-container">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display=\'none\'"
  class="w3-button w3-gray w3-large w3-display-topright">&times;</span>


<div id=\'alerts_create_room\' class=\'w3-panel w3-red\'>No Data Found for the Search Group.</div></div>';
```

Or:

```
echo '<div class=" w3-display-container">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display=none"
  class="w3-button w3-gray w3-large w3-display-topright">&times;</span>


<div id="alerts_create_room" class="w3-panel w3-red">No Data Found for the Search Group.</div></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Give backslash "\" in every your "single quotes"

```
<span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display=\'none\'" class="w3-button w3-gray w3-large w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
```

and

```
<div id=\'alerts_create_room\' class=\'w3-panel w3-red\'>
```